# Three.js Map material showing warnings despite updating buffers

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, webgl

I'm trying to load an OBL object and, on pre-specified containers (plains) display a texture. However, after I load an object, I start getting the following errors:

```
THREE.WebGLRenderer 58 
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8000/original-material/room2/soba-5-2.obj".

about to traverse... 
about to add to scene 

WebGLRenderingContext: GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 0
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.
```

Following [Three JS Map Material causes WebGL Warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531759/three-js-map-material-causes-webgl-warning), I explicitly started to set following flags, although I had (even beforehand) modified material attributes before adding anything to the scene.

```
child.material.needsUpdate = true;
child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

Despite this, problem still persists. Any ideas?

---

## Code

```
var container_re_match = /container_/

console.log('about to traverse...');
data.traverse(function(child){
    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
        child.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
                ambient: 0xff0000, color: 0xffffff, specular: 0xffffff, shininess: 30, shading: THREE.SmoothShading});

        if (child.parent.name.match(container_re_match)) {
            var container_data = CONTAINER_DATA[child.parent.name]

            child.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(container_data.image);
            child.material.needsUpdate = true;
            child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
            child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
        }
    }
});
console.log('about to add to scene');
scene.add(data) // Adding only after everything has been processed
}
```

Comment: Texture loading is asynchronous. Try `child.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( image, null, function( child ) { child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate; child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate; } );` The loader sets the `material.needsUpdate` flag.

Comment: @WestLangley I was thinking that maybe async loading might be an issue, but it doesn't do any good... even explicitly setting `child.material.map` in async call didn't help `child.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(container_data.image, null, function(texture){ child.material.map = texture;  child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true; child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true; });`

Comment: Try starting with a dummy white texture to begin with, so the geometry will have the necessarey UV buffers. If that doesn't work, then provide a SIMPLE live example -- not your whole project. Also, I'd suggest you update to r.60.

Comment: @WestLangley I tried uploading it to jsfiddle but had a problems due to loading OBJ files. Anyway, [here is the most barebones example that I could make](http://static.domenkozar.com/demo-external/demo.html). I used another .obj file than in previous example, updated to r60 and updated the example to reflect changes in r60 that are in `webgl_loader_obj` example. This time I'm not getting previously mentioned warning, but still get `PERFORMANCE WARNING: Some textures are unrenderable.`. Tried with `OBJMTLLoader` as well, with no luck.

Comment: Oh, and [ZIP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1493539/demo-external.zip) and [github](https://github.com/uskudnik/threejs-texture-demo) for easier editing

Comment: On OSX I get no warnings with Chrome or Safari. You have no vertex normals, only face normals in you barebones example. The light is not shining on the front faces. Set `light.position.set( 1, 0, 0 );`. The `needsUpdate` flags are not required because this is the first rendering. Your  UVs are unusual, but I got the squares to render brown. (Oh. I answered before I saw the zip file.)

Comment: Well, setting the light did light them brown, but I'm not sure why that would be happening since I would like to put crate texture on each of the planes... (crate.gif from `webgl_geometry_cube` example). I was thinking that issue might be in scaling, but after manually expanding in blender (I think) I ruled that out as well. (I get those warnings if I turn on the GL Inspector.)

Comment: This has turned into a help-me-debug-my-code question, which is not the purpose of this site. If you need more help, make a new post, and try to ask a specific question that will be helpful to others. Thank you for providing a simple example. It made it easier to help you.

Comment: Seems like something is wrong with geometry.