# Collada model disappears after changing materials Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js, textures, mesh, collada

I am trying to change the material of a Collada model exported from Sketchup:

I have used:

```
dae.traverse(function(child) {
     if (child.material!==undefined) {
         if (child.material.materials===undefined) {
                child.material.map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/monster.jpg", null, function( child ) { 
                                      child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate; 
                                      child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate;
                                });
                          } else {
                                
                                for (var j=0;j<child.material.materials.length;j++) 
                                      child.material.materials[j].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "textures/monster.jpg", null, function( child ) { 
                                      child.material.materials[j].needsUpdate;
                                      child.geometry.buffersNeedUpdate; 
                                      child.geometry.uvsNeedUpdate;
                                      });
                                };
                          };     
              };
                   
        });
```

However when I try to change the texture map, or even the entire texture, my geometry disappears completely.

I have seen this, but it was not helpful. [Three.js Map material showing warnings despite updating buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317637/three-js-map-material-showing-warnings-despite-updating-buffers)

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

### UPDATE:

Changing my material from MeshLambertMaterial to ShaderMaterial makes the geometry appear, but it is red. (It should be a porcelain white). Should I not be using MeshLambertMaterial for a complex Collada model?

Comment: Are your textures' dimensions power of two?

Comment: not sure what the problem here is, but you do not need the BuffersNeedUpdate and UVs need update when changing a texture. 

Also, check if your texture allocation works on the correct objects etc.

Comment: @GuyGood If I change my material from MeshLambertMaterial to ShaderMaterial, I can see the geometry, but it is completely red.

Comment: Did you find the answer by any chance ?