# WebGL Warning when adding texture to material map in Three.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a JSON file (map.js) from which I load my geometry and material settings (this is a file I generated, and it is too large for me to manually edit it). It looks something like this:

```
"materials": [  {
"DbgColor" : 2632490,
"DbgIndex" : 0,
"DbgName" : "ASPHALT_0"
},

{
"DbgColor" : 16777215,
"DbgIndex" : 1,
"DbgName" : "ROAD_MARKING_DASHED_0"
}],

"vertices": [-370.412496,0.000000,120.194495...

"morphTargets": [],

"morphColors": [],

"normals": [],

"colors": [],

"uvs": [[]],

"faces": [2,0,1,2,0...
```

Note for faces format: triangle with material

I'm loading this file like this:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load("map.js", function(geometry, materials){
    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materials));
    scene.add(mesh);
    loadRestOfScene();
});
```

What I want to do is to add a texture to a specific material in my materials array. Something like:

```
materials[i].map = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'road.jpg' );
```

But when I load my page I get this warning:

**[.WebGLRenderingContext]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_OPERATION : glDrawElements: attempt to access out of range vertices in attribute 2 index.html:1
WebGL: too many errors, no more errors will be reported to the console for this context.**

I've read similar questions (and answers) here, and tried to do:

```
materials.needsUpdate = true;
geometry.buffersNeedUpdate = true;
geometry.uvsNeedUpdate = true;
```

But this doesn't change anything. Is it even posible to add a texture to a material that doesn't have it initially? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Make sure you have UVs and read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16531759/three-js-map-material-causes-webgl-warning/16533812#16533812.

Comment: As you can see from my question, I've read that post, because I've tried to do what you said (I quote): "Alternatively, you can begin with a textureless material, and then set the following flags when a texture is added..." 
And I don't have UVs because the code that generates my JSON file doesn't creates UVs, and that is something that I can't change.

Comment: If you don't have UVs, then why are you trying to add a texture?

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify which material needs an update

```
materials[i].needsUpdate = true;
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything.